# How to make vim insert same amount of spaces on tab?

Tags: vim

I would like on pressing `<Tab>` for vim to insert the same amount of spaces each time. It seems that it doesn't do this by default but instead aligns to the nearest multiple of `tabstop` from the start of the line.

For example, consider I have the following config in my `.vimrc`

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

The arrow shows what happens on pressing `<Tab>` after typing `hi`. The vertical line `|` indicates the vim cursor's new position.

This is the current situation:

```
hi->|
1234| // Aligned to a 4 space boundary
```

However, this is what I am looking for:

```
hi--->|
123456| // Exactly 4 spaces from 'i'
```

Comment: why on earth should you want that? (Serious question, I am not trying to mock you).

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo haha I get disappointed when I hit <Tab> and see less than 4 spaces added. Imagine pressing 'i' and only sometimes going into insert mode.

Comment: but the whole idea behind the tab key, is to align stuff on a tabstop. I can't imagine a usecase where I always want to insert 4 spaces. Maybe you should try to describe what problem you have with the classical tab key. I am fairly certain there would be another solution to this.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo hmm maybe you're right. I recall being annoyed by it, but now that I think about it not having easy alignment is probably worse. If I find a use case I'll tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map tab key to 4 spaces during insert mode:

`:imap <tab> <space><space><space><space>`

Comment: I think you mean 4 <space>s. Also, why isn't this the default behaviour?

Comment: "Also, why isn't this the default behaviour?" It's not and will never be the default behaviour in any plain or rich text editor ever. People have used the Tab key to push the next typed character to the next tabulation since before computers. That's literally the whole point of that key.